# Not displaying an entry that is in a certain category but also in other categories

Tags: categories

We're trying to display certain elements based on whether they are in a category or not.

We have the following:

Type Category group

- Type1
- Type2
- Type3

Range category group

- Range1
- Range2

I want to display all of Type 1 in a page, all of Type 2 in a page and all of Type 3 page. However I don't want Range2 items to show up on these pages.

We've used code like this (1 is Type1 category ID and 5 is Range2):

{exp:channel:entries channel="product" category="1 not 5" dynamic="no" orderby="title" sort="asc"}

The problem we have is that if an item is part of Type1 and Range2, it'll still show up. Which is correct according to EE documentation (https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#category), however how can I go about making this work the way I want to? Is it possible with standard EE or do i need an additional module installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using stash to do this, not sure it's possible with just standalone EE, if it is though i'd love to know!